# How to filter a model through multiple forms?

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform, modelchoicefield

I have a single Car model which I'd like to filter through interdependent ModelChoiceField's:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Forms.py:

```
class MakeSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    make = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Car.objects.values_list('make',flat=True).distinct())
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ["make"]

class ModelSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Car.objects.values_list('model',flat=True).distinct())
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ["make", "model"]
```

Views.py:

```
def make_select_view(request):
    form = MakeSelectForm()
    make = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MakeSelectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            make = form.cleaned_data['make']
    return render(request, "reviews/makeselect.html", {"form": form, "make": make})

def model_select_view(request, make):
    form = ModelSelectForm()
    model = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MakeSelectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            model = form.cleaned_data['model']
    return render(request, "reviews/modelselect.html", {"form": form, "model": model})
```

URL's:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.make_select_view, name="make-select"),
    url(r'^(?P<make>\w+)/$', views.model_select_view, name="model-select"),
]
```

Makeselect.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'reviews:model-select' make %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Select" />
</form>
```

Now, I have to pass "make" argument of the first form when posted, to the second view, and then use it to filter through Car instances with that make. But here all I pass is "None", and get *Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.* error in the second form.

Any suggestion or feedback will be welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to pass the information that you got from first form to the second form via second view. I think that you would need to override the `__init__` of the second form to adjust the queryset for the desired field. Following is what I did back in the day


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(GameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.request.user.is_staff:
            self.fields['publisher'].queryset = Publisher.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point: model forms are for creating / editing models, so you should use plain forms here. Your error comes from having the `make` field in your `ModelSelectForm` but not setting its value anywhere. Also, `ModelChoiceField` is meant to retrieve a model instance, not field's value, so you really want a `ChoiceField` here.

Second point, since your goal is to display filtered informations - not to create or edit anything -, you should use `GET` queries (like for any "search" feature actually).

For your second form to work as expected (once ported to a plain `Form` with a single `model` field), you'll need to pass the `make` value to the form and, in the form's `__init__()`, update the `model` fields choices to the filtered queryset.

Also since you'll be using `GET` as form's method, you'll have to check wether the form has been submitted at all before deciding to instanciate it with or without the `request.GET` data, else the users would get error messages on first display before they even had a chance to submit anything. This is usually solved using either a name and value for the form's submit button or a hidden field in the form itself:

Forms:

```
class  ModelSelectForm(forms.Form):
    model = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        make = kwargs.pop("make", None)
        if not make:
            raise ValueError("expected a 'make' keyword arg")
        super(ModelSelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = Car.objects.filter(make=make).values_list('model',flat=True).distinct()
        choices = [(value, value) for value in qs]
        self.fields["model"].choices = choices
```

Views:

```
def model_select_view(request, make):
    model = None
    if request.GET.get("submitted", None):
        form = ModelSelectForm(request.GET, make=make)
        if form.is_valid():
            model = form.cleaned_data['model']
    else:
        form = ModelSelectForm(make=make)
    context = {"form": form, "model": model, "make: make}
    return render(request, "reviews/modelselect.html", context)
```

Templates:

```
<form action="{% url 'reviews:model-select' make %}" method="GET">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Select" />
</form>
```

wrt/ your question about "passing 'make' to the second view": there's nowhere in your code snippet where you direct the user to the `model-select` view, but I assume that what you want is the user being redirected to it once he successfully selected the "make" in the first view. If yes, your first view's code should handle the case on successful form submission, ie:

```
def make_select_view(request):
    if request.GET.get("submitted", None):
        form = MakeSelectForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            make = form.cleaned_data['make']
            # send the user to the model selection view
            return redirect("reviews:model-select", make=make)

    else:
        form = MakeSelectForm()
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "reviews/makeselect.html", context)
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. I made the changes, then edited my **MakeSelectForm** and **make_select_view** [accordingly](http://oi67.tinypic.com/23kzxq0.jpg). However, I still can't pass selected "make" to the second view, such is its URL: _/None/?submitted=1&make=BMW_ If I change "None" manually, filtering works.

Comment: You didn't specify how you go from the first view to the second one and it's nowhere in your code snippet. But I added a canonical example in the answer, redirecting from the first view to the second one on successful submission.

Comment: Thanks once again. I thought that redirection was done in the template, by `form action="{% url 'reviews:model-select' make %}"`. Anyway, [I edited my code](http://oi66.tinypic.com/240yw3p.jpg) but still get "None" instead of selected make.

Comment: The form's `action` params tells the browser where to submit the form, not where to redirect the user if the form submission is successful. Most of the time you'll want the form to be handled by the view that displayed it (which is usually done by setting the form's action to `"#"` or just a plain `""`).

Comment: wrt/ your "still getting None" problem, in makeselect.html, you set the form's action to `{% url 'reviews:model-select' make %}'.  That's NOT what you want, cf my above comment, and at this point `make` is indeed garanteed to be `None`. Just set the form's action to an empty string and handle the redirect in the view as in my answer.

Comment: Oh I got it now. Thank you so much, your support is much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. You may still want to read about the HTML spec (specially the `form` tag and it's attributes) and the HTTP protocol (request/response cycle and the correct use of verbs) if you hope to get web programming right ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since the formatting of the snippet that I posted in comment got messed up so, I am writing that as an answer here.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(GameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.request.user.is_staff:
        self.fields['publisher'].queryset = Publisher.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
```